# Bad request when updating Appengine with mvn appengine:update

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-plugin

i'm getting the following error, when I try to update a appengine-application with the appengine-maven-plugin:

```
400 Bad Request
Error when loading application configuration:
Unable to assign value '1.8.3' to attribute 'version':
Value '1.8.3' for version does not match expression '^(?:^(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,62}[a-z\d]$)$'
```

This is confusing to my because my appengine-web.xml looks like follows:

```xml
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>helloworld</application>
    <version>0-0-1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <precompilation-enabled>false</precompilation-enabled>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I'm wondering why appengine-maven-plugin wants to use 1.8.3 as application-version. 1.8.3 is the version of appengine-sdk i want to use.
In my POM it's configured as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>${appengine.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and later on

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${appengine.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <appVersion>${appengine.app.version}</appVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

${appengine.app.version} points to 1.8.3
I'm using Maven in Version 3.1 and Java 1.7.0_25

What do I wrong? Can anyone help my?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue as you described.  When I added the "version" element in the configuration element, with value pointing to the version of the app in my appengine-web.xml file, `mvn appengine:update` completed successfully.  (maven v3.1.0, appengine plugin v1.8.3)

in pom.xml:

```
....
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${appengine.version}</version>
   <configuration>
      <version>MY-VERSION</version>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

in appengine-web.xml:

```
...
<version>MY-VERSION</version>
...
```

Comment: this answer really helped

Comment: This worked for me but it is not ideal to have to keep the version in two separate locations.

Comment: You can define a Maven property and use it in both locations.

Answer (score 5):

If you generated the project with the archetype skeleton, like I did, and you have a block similar to

```
<properties>
    <app.id>MY-GAE-PROJECT-ID</app.id>
    <app.version>1</app.version>
    <appengine.version>1.9.20</appengine.version>
    <gcloud.plugin.version>0.9.58.v20150505</gcloud.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

in your pom.xml and your appengine-web.xml looked like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>${app.id}</application>
<version>1</version>
etc....
```

when it got made, then, modify appengine-web.xml to be ${app.version} because they so helpfully already added that property with the archetype but never used it anywhere. Then, update your pom.xml's app.version to be your appropriate version (if you don't use "1"). Then, scroll down in the pom.xml to where you see

```
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
```

and inside the configuration block there add

```
                <version>${app.version}</version>
```

Comment: The 2013 solution didn't work for me, but this one did with 1.9.21

Answer (score 0):

Try to change appengine-web.xml entry from `<version>0-0-1</version>` to `<version>1</version>`. Regards, Adam.

Answer (score 0):

In changed only the pom.xml file by adding the plugin>configuration>version tag (per below)...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${project.appengine.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <port>8888</port>
     *<version>${app.version}</version>*
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this issue was trivial in my console I executed `mvn clean install` and then the `appcfg.cmd -A [your app] update target\appengine-try-java-1.0` command.