# Google Appengine appengine.version

Tags: java, regex, maven, google-app-engine

I'm following Google's guide here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading

I've followed step by step, so it matches perfectly. I've almost finished it, I'm at step 2, which has me run the following:

```
mvn appengine:update
```

It has me authenticate, which goes fine, but then it throws this error:

> 400 Bad Request Error when loading application configuration:Unable to
>   assign value '1.9.18' to attribute 'version':Value '1.9.18' for
>   version does not match expression
>   '^(?:^(?!-)[a-z\d-]{0,62}[a-z\d]$)$'

Looking into the pom.xml file, it shows:

```
        <appengine.version>1.9.18</appengine.version>
```

It's true this doesn't match that regular expression. So I tested, and changed "1.9.18" to "1-9-18", which does match it. Sadly, it then gives this error:

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org .codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\James.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Am I missing something? It seems like the regular expression or something else is out of date, and won't let me continue.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18239234/4428462) helps ?

Comment: That did help, but it's still got some errors.I've added this:  
`code` <myversion>1.9.18</myversion>  
and used it lower down such as:  
`code`<version>${myversion}</version>  
It seemed to fix that particular issue. However, other plugins are now not working, showing the following:  
`code`The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1-9-18, com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:jar:1-9-18  
amongst others. When making those plugins use #{myversion}, it reverts back to saying it doesn't match '^(?:^(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,62}[a-z\d]$)$'

Comment: Jackpot. While working with the link you provided I had put "<version>1.9.18</version>" in the <configuration> section of the plugin causing issues. This was to hopefully override $<appengine.version>, but didn't. Turns out it was breaking it. Putting "<myversion>1.9.18</myversion>" in the <properties> section above and using it below "<artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>" worked. Final output: Update for module default completed successfully.
Success.  

Thank you for your link!

Comment: Glad it helped you :-) You can _accept_ your own answer, and then everyone will see that you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link: [Bad request when updating Appengine with mvn appengine:update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18239234/4428462)  pointed me in the right direction. In pom.xml, inside of `<properties>`, I added

```
<myversion>1.9.18</myversion>
```

and modified this one

`<appengine.version>1-9-18</appengine.version>`

Then lower down had the version referenced like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${myversion}</version>
    ...
</plugin>
```

I did not need to edit appengine-web.xml

Comment: Not working I did all the steps mentioned above but it is showing

Error when loading application configuration:Unable to assign value '1.9.18' to
attribute 'version':Value '1.9.18' for version does not match expression '^(?:^(
?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,62}[a-z\d]$)$'

Answer (score 0):

Try this
in your pom.xml:

```
<appengine.target.version>1.9.18</appengine.target.version>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include a description *why* this might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the important thing is to understand the meaning of this configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <!--the plugin and the version is the plugin version number-->
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${appengine.version}</version>
    <!--this is the application version, when you set a different version number, you will get a new version app on the cloud after you process the deploy-->
    <configuration>
      <version>1</version>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For example:

The previous version is **1**,

if you set the  to 1, you will get update of previous version **xxx.appspot.com**.

if you set the  to 2, you will get new version of the app, such as **2-dot-XXX.appspot.com**.

so for this version number, you cannot use `.`, because you cannot use dot in the domain name (in actual, the sub-domain of appspot). You need use `-` replace the `.`